# Why my computer doesn't recoqnize other devices on the same network if they connect to different routers?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have an ISP. It broadcasts WiFi on the SSID Playmedia.

Then I have a xiaomi router. It gets Internet connection from Playmedia and makes it available to my other devices. It broadcasts under the SSIDs xiaomi and xiaomi5g (depending on whether it's using 5 GHz frequency or 2.4 normal GHz frequency).

If I connect two computers, one to xiaomi and another to xiaomi5g, I can remote desktop to one another.

If I connect two computers, one to playmedia and the other to xiaomi, I cannot remote desktop to one another.

I suppose I can work something out so that my xiaomi router simply "extends" the Playmedia SSID. I don't know how to do so yet.

If I look at IP this is what I have:

- Playmedia: 192.168.1.1
- Xiaomi router: 192.168.1.5
- My computer:  192.168.1.12
- Another computer: 192.168.1.11

Because the other computers have similar IPs and they differ only by one I conclude that another computer is on the same network.

I can't connect though.

However, if I tell another computer to connect to xiaomi router, then I can.

What should I do?

1. Tell xiaomi router to act as repeater so that the whole house uses the same network?
2. Tell Windows that computers on playmedia network are in the same network with computers that connect to xiaomi router
3. Connect all other computers to xiaomi router. The problem with this method is is the IP remain the same. I can connect using remote desktop though. But that means I won't be able to remote desktop to another computer all the way in 3rd floor.

What?

Answer (score 1):

> If I connect two computers, one to playmedia and the other to xiaomi, I cannot remote desktop to one another....Because the other computers have similar IPs and they differ only by one I conclude that another computer is on the same network.

Your conclusion is incorrect.

First, the xiaomi router creates a second, separate network and blocks traffic from the ISP/Playmedia network destined to the xiaomi network.

Second, your two networks are using overlapping IP addressing schemes, preventing the routers from being able to route traffic destined to the other network. In other words, if "My computer" with IP 192.168.1.12 is on one network and 
"Another computer" with IP 192.168.1.11 is on the other network, both computers expect the other PC to be on the *same* network (not separated by a router). As a result they cannot connect to each other.

> What should I do?

That depends on your goals. Based on the fact you expect to be able to remote desktop between computers on your two networks, it sounds like you need a single network. If so, then configuring the xiaomi router to act as a repeater would be a good solution.

If there are only specific services, such as Remote Desktop, that you need to access between the two networks, another solution would be to:

1. Change the IP addressing of the xiaomi router's network to something else, such as 192.168.2.0/24, and
2. Configure port forwarding on the xiaomi router to allow the desired services from the ISP network to the xiaomi network.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand, your ISP is a wireless ISP that broadcasts "playmedia" SSID. You are then using your Xiaomi router to create your own network and using the "playmedia" network as a WAN connection.

Now there are three possible reasons why you aren't able to connect to your PC from outside the Network.

1. NETWORK SUBNET - The devices aren't actually aren't in the same subnet, i.e. are different networks. Meaning what 192.168.0.11 means on one Network might not mean the same on other. You need to Port forward the device inside your Xiaomi network to wan/ISP network. (ALSO REFER FIREWALL BELOW) **THIS IS EXTREMELY UNSAFE FOR REGULAR HOME USE. YOU ARE ALLOWING ANYONE CONNECTED TO CONNECT TO TOUR DEVICE FROM THE INTERNET/ON ISPs network.**
2. FIREWALL - Your router has Firewall that disallows outside connections. You need to add an exception to your Firewall to allow connection from outside the network. Refer the manual or search for instructions along with the specific model number for your Xiaomi router. (Try your luck though, as far as i know xiomi routers all have very limited functionality and afaik, Xiaomi routers have just very basic all or none switch toggle for Firewall) also, again this is unsafe if playmedia is your ISPs network.
3. Network Isolation - devices on your ISPs network is isolated from each other. This means devices on same network can't directly reach each other. This is common on WIFI based ISPs. There is nothing you can do in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Xiaomi router creates own subnet with same IP range, but it's not the same network. You should either connect xiaomi to ISP as LAN device (not WAN). I don't know those routers, so I don't know how to do it, but for sure there is an option for this. Or you could just connect ISP to Xiaomi's LAN port, not WAN port.